# How do web browsers on iOS play Flash?

Tags: ios, flash, uiwebview

I noticed this web browser, Photon ([iTunes Store link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photon-flash-player-for-iphone/id453546382?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)) is able to play flash. My question is, if Apple doesn't allow flash to run on devices and all web browsers must use Apple's UIWebView, how can this app enable Flash playback?

Answer (score 0):

Most third party apps route flash video to a there own Server to be re-encoded to another Safari friendly file format such as mp4. Once the was bee re-encoded it sent back to there client device

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in the app itself? I don't want to have to maintain and pay for an external server.

Comment: nope there no available frameworks that support flash decoding or even any open source tools that i can find...